# Bootstrap responsive image issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I'm new to this whole Bootstrap scene.
Trying to put an image as a navbar brand and have it resized when the windows does

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img alt="Brand" src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" /></a>
```

I've also tried `img-fluid` and adding `style='width:100%'`, but nothing works and its size is always static.

Comment: I dont think the brand icon will change according to the window resize. Brand icon is meant to stay the same.

Comment: see here: https://jsfiddle.net/narv0d46/ - it is working!

Answer (score 0):

Put on the image the `max-width:100%`, shall work

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
a {
  display: block;
  width: /* depending on how much space you wanted for your navbar-brand */
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With images you'd want to add:

```
.img-responsive {
    height: auto;    // the height will be in the images correct aspect ratio.
    max-width: 100%; //Keep the image width the same as it's parents container. 
}
```

Comment: Just because he's added the class it doesn't mean the class has the styling I've suggested?

Comment: How about having a look here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive. the class already applies max-width: 100%;, height: auto; and display: block;

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working well.
I've tried same code here. Please check.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img alt="Brand" src="http://img.logospectrum.com/dec/dummy-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" /></a>
```